# Let $A+I$ be invertible. Show that $(A+I)^{-1}$ and $(I-A)$ commute

Tags: linear-algebra

Not really sure where to start with this one. I'm rather terrible with proofs and all, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are asked to show that two things commute. That is, you want to start with $(A+I)^{-1}(I-A)$ and somehow obtain $(I-A)(A+I)^{-1}$. What have you tried so far?

EDIT(hint): $(A+I)^{-1}A=\left(A^{-1}(A+I)\right)^{-1}$

Comment: Well I'm a little foggy with what the question wants, but that's what it asked. So I'm assuming that want me to prove that some how that (A+I)^-1(I-A) = (I-A)(A+I)^-1 .   As far as my understanding of this goes I've tired multiplying by the inverse of (A+I) to eliminate it on one side, but that didn't seem to help me out.

Comment: you want to start with one side, manipulate it, and try to obtain the other side. Setting them equal to eachother on the outset is assuming the result.

Comment: @Prototank this method can work sometimes, i.e if all steps are done with iffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(A+I)^{-1} (I-A) &= (A+I)^{-1} (I-A) \,I\\
&= (A+I)^{-1} (I-A) \left[ (A+I)(A+I)^{-1} \right] \\
&= (A+I)^{-1} \left[ (I-A)(I+A) \right] (A+I)^{-1} \\
&= (A+I)^{-1} \left[ (I+A)(I-A) \right] (A+I)^{-1} \\
&= \left[ (A+I)^{-1} (I+A)\right](I-A) (A+I)^{-1} \\
&= I\, (I-A) (A+I)^{-1}\\
&= (I-A) (A+I)^{-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: It took me a bit to figure out what you did, but then I realized that in this case I = [(A+I)(A+I)^-1] Which really helped clarify the steps that I needed to take in order to get the results. Thank you, and thank you everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably best to first prove the general theorem: If $X$ and $Y$ commute and $X$ is invertible, then $X^{-1}$ and $Y$ commute.

Proof:
\begin{align}
X^{-1}Y
&= X^{-1}YI && \text{($I$ is neutral element of multiplication)}\\
&= X^{-1}YXX^{-1} && \text{(definition of $X^{-1}$)}\\
&= X^{-1}XYX^{-1} && \text{($X$ and $Y$ commute)}\\
&= IYX^{-1} && \text{(definition of $X^{-1}$, again)}\\
&= YX^{-1} && \text{(neutrality of $I$ again)}
\end{align}
Note that in the calculation above I implicitly used the associativity of matrix multiplication by not writing any parentheses. Note also that the above calculation is not specific for matrices, but works in any monoid.

Having this general result, for proving that $(A+I)^{-1}$ and $(I-A)$ commute, all that remains to show is that $(A+I)$ and $(I-A)$ commute. But that is easily done by direct calculation.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$(A+I)(A-I)=(A-I)(A+I)=A^2-I$ implies that $(A+I)(A-I)(A+I)^{-1}=(A-I)$. This implies that $(A+I)^{-1}(A+I)(A-I)(A+I)^{-1}=(A+I)^{-1}(A-I)$. This implies that $(A-I)(A+I)^{-1}=(A+I)^{-1}(A-I)$